# dash/plotly how can I add a calendar/agenda/schedule view

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have created my own dashboard and would like to add a new tab with a calendar/schedule or task manager/viewer; as an example, would it be possible to come up with something like [image: this (windows 11 Calendar]

On that picture I am mostly interested in the overall Month view (and the scroll down feature) in the center-right.
My "Calendar" would only run for the next 4 months and would be fed from a database (a table birthdays, a table appointments, a bank_holidays table...). A birthday would show up in yellow for instance while an appointment would be in red and a bank_holidays in blue. It wouldn't be dynamic as the Calendar would be initialized upon a button clicked and the data would be "frozen" until the next day/click of a button. From what I found this is far from being straightforward. I thought (think) I could have used the DatePickerRange and instead of having the calendar popping-up, having a way to have this calendar fixed/static within my page.

If this is not possible to be done intuitively based on dash/plotly I was thinking I need to  create my own calendar template based on dash datatable: one datatable for each upcoming months (max 4 months). How can I initialized a dataframe to represent a month, with columns being the day of the week, and the values per rows being the day of that month?

My idea would then to cast those values into a list and then append the dates from my birthday table, appointment table and so on.

Edit: it seems there are some Calendar templates based on javascript, but then how can I embed such template into my dash/plotly dashboard?

Comment: Any luck on this? I'd like to be able to have a simple month or year calendar view with multiple events showing up, either in dash or streamlit

Comment: No luck. I created a single app with PyQt: there it is quite straightforward to implement a calendar similar to the screenshot in my original post.